# python code not reading first line in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this piece of code that is supposed to iterate over every line in a file, then add each line to a list, then strip that list (to get rid of spaces and \n's), and then finally appends those list items to one big list. This list contains every word from every sentence from every line in the file.
The code I have here does exactly except for one detail, it skips the first line for some reason.

```
def counter(words):
    frequency = {}
    for word in words:
        if word not in frequency:
            frequency[word] = 1
        elif word in frequency:
            frequency[word] += 1
    return frequency


def main():
    print("This program shows the frequency of words in a file.\n"
          "Could you please enter the file name, without extension?")
    file_name = input('') + '.txt'
    with open(file_name, "r") as word_file:
        words = []
        for lines in word_file:
            for line in lines:
                line = word_file.readline()
                temp_words = line.split()
                print(temp_words)
                for word in temp_words:
                    words.append(word)
    print(counter(words))
```

This is the whole code but you guys only need to focus on the main function, thank youu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some redundancy:

```
for lines in word_file:  # this will move the iterator one forward
  for line in lines: # this actually iterates through the chars in the line
    line = word_file.readline()  # but this moves the iterator ahead, too
```

The following will suffice to replace the for loop:

```
for line in word_file:
  words.extend(line.split())
```

Btw, your core program can be written as:

```
from collections import Counter
with open(file_name, "r") as word_file:
  c = Counter(word for line in word_file for word in line.split())
print(c)
```

Comment: Thank you, man.
I'm still a noob at python ;p
(I'll give your answer a check mark as soon as I can, gotta wait ten more minutes)